# Android spinner increment number

Tags: java, android

I want to create a spinner in android which has a list from 0 to 255. I was wondering how i go about doing this?

I currently have this...

```
 public void addItemsOnSpinner() {

        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("list 1");
        list.add("list 2");
        list.add("list 3");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }
```

I don't have much experience with java, so really just want the spinner to start at 0 and increment to 255 going up by one at a time.

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your code for this:

```
public void addItemsOnSpinner() {

        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i=0; i<=255; i++){
            list.add("list " + i);
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a custom adapter that return the value of the position up to 255:

```
public class CountAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public CountAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 255;
    }
    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return String.valueOf(position);
    }
}
```

This way you don't have to create a 255 items list. 255 can obviously be parametrized in the constructor for instance. Or in a setter (don't forget to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` in this case)

Answer (score 1):

Just create a for loop that repeats 255 times and each time adds the current index to the list. Try something like this:

```
final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

for(int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
    String item = String.valueOf(i);
    list.add(item);
}

ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
...
```